# I have an Array of 2 objects, when I use a for loop, both of the object gets the change that only one of them should have

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, libgdx, box2d

Basically I have this code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < tnt.size; i++){

        TNT t = tnt.get(i);

        if(cl.isLeft()){ t.getBody().setLinearVelocity(6,0); }

        if(cl.isRight()){t.getBody().setLinearVelocity(-6,0); } 

        if(t.getBody().getPosition().x > 1888/PPM){t.getBody().setLinearVelocity(-6,0);     }

        if(t.getBody().getPosition().x < 31/PPM){t.getBody().setLinearVelocity(6,0);}



    }
```

What happens is if I have 2 objects in this Array, when something happens to object #1 it gets a change in how it should act, but object #2 gets the same change as object #1. I want them to act independently, so how would I do that?

Here is a GIF of what happens: https://gfycat.com/HelplessEmotionalCornsnake
When the object(TNT) touches a wall it should change direction, but here they both change direction when only one should.

Comment: by **not** using for loop and **not** applying it for both objects?

Comment: You are changing both the objects in the for loop. You need to distinguish the objects first, i.e. apply these changes only to TNT that is crashing with the wall. Inside the loop, changes gets applied to all the objects in  tnt  array.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! @RaviRanjan how do I distinguish the objects in the loop? (sorry for not knowing much, i'm new to programming)

Comment: i am not much into graphics and all, but i guess you can track the x - y axis of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code seems to be right. I don't think your mistake is in the code, you posted.

Please show us your TNT-class- and the class getBody() is referring. Do you use any static Methods/Variables? If for example setLinearVelocity() or the variable of your movement direction is static, this behaviour is normal, because static Methods/Variables are the same for all instances.

Are you sure, the two body-objets of both TNT classes are different? Check if tnt.get(0).getBody() != tnt.get(1).getBody().

**Update:**
Forget everything:

You are calling "cl.isVänster()". What does this code mean? cl shouldn't change while running your for-loop, so cl.isVänster() and cl.isHöger() also returns the same value for every tnt-object.

Comment: I did this code : if(tnt.get(0).getBody() != tnt.get(1).getBody()){System.out.println("working");}  It does print out "working".

Comment: Please explain me, what cl.isVänster() does. This won't change, because cl doesn't change. So for every tnt-Object in your loop, you are actually doing the same.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was that cl.Vänster() and cl.Höger() wasnt specified to a specific object in the array. Now it's fixed!  http://gfycat.com/TatteredBoringClingfish